# Roots of polynomial in $R[X],$ where $R$ is $\text{UFD}.$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a $\text{UFD},$ with field of fractions $F$ and let $f(X)=a_0+a_1X+...+a_nX^n \in R[X]$ such that $a_n \neq 0.$ Let $x\in F$ be a root of $f(X).$

Could anyone advise me on how to show $x=\dfrac{r}{s},$ for some $r,s \in R, s \neq 0$ satisfying $r|a_0,s|a_n$ in $R \ ?$

Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: if $r/s$ is a root of $f$, then $x-r/s$ divides $f$ in $F$. Now use the fact that $R[x]$ is a UFD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$0=f\left(\frac rs\right)=a_n\left(\frac rs\right)^n+\ldots+a_1\left(\frac rs\right)+a_0\implies $$

$$a_nr^n=-a_{n-1}sr^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1rs^{n-1}+a_0s^n$$

Right side is divided by $\;s\;$ so also is left side, and we can assume the fraction $\;\frac rs\;$ is reduced, so...

Do now something similar to the above to prove that also $\;r\mid a_0\;$ ...

Comment: Thank you. This means $\text{gcd}(r,s)=1,$ so $s|a_n$ in $R ?$

Comment: Well, it means that **if** we have $\;gcd(r,s)=1\;$ then...etc.